# Arduino IDE not able to Upload Sketch (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, arduino-ide, avrdude

I've recently switched to a Linux Machine and tried to set up my Arduino IDE for a little project. Unfortunatly I get an error message when I try to upload my sketch to the Arduino (Uno R3).

> User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file,skipping.         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
>            Using Programmer              : arduino
>            Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
>   avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
>   avrdude done.  Thank you.

My user is part of the **dialout** group, and when I use avrdude manually evrything is fine. The error persits even when I change access permissions to **rw-rw-rw-**.

I tried to reinstall the IDE, to switch to an older version, to switch to a newer version, nothing worked so far.

The version I've currently installed is Arduino 1.8.5.

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands in the terminal, it should work!

```
>>ls /dev/ttyACM0

>>sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

>>ls /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: Please write the commands you're showing us as text instead of an image. It's much easier for people who need help to use your answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with the Arduino IDE 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
(Re)installing AVRDUDE helped.

`sudo apt install avrdude`

AVRDUDE is the program that downloads (flashes) the compiled code onto the AVR microcontroller that is the heart of the Arduino board. It seems like the Arduino IDE doesn't integrate or install AVRDUDE properly.